# React typescript Vite Project to Docker - Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, vite

I have a react-typescript-vite app which I am trying to dockerise.
My vite.config looks like this

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true, // needed for the Docker Container port mapping to work
    strictPort: true,
    port: 5173, // you can replace this port with any port
  },
});
```

My docker file looks like this

```
FROM node:20 AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json before other files
# Utilize Docker cache to save re-installing dependencies if unchanged
COPY sv_ui_v1/package.json .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm i

# Copy all files
COPY . .

# Build app

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I used to get the error Failed to resolve entry for package "./app". the package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in package.json. So then I added  "main": "src/main.tsx", to my package.json. Now nothing is working except a 404 error. Can anyone help?